# Ionic2 Google map not showing

Tags: angular, ionic2, cordova-plugins

Everyone 
I want to use google map in my application. I have installed cordova plugin googlemaps with Api key for both Android and ios. The problem I'm facing is just showing the google logo and zooming buttons, the entire area for map is blank. I am following this tutorial http://www.joshmorony.com/integrating-native-google-maps-into-an-ionic-2-application/. please guide what I am doing wrong. Thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N99zf.jpg)

**order-tracking.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {
    GoogleMap,
    GoogleMapsEvent,
    GoogleMapsLatLng,
    CameraPosition,
    GoogleMapsMarkerOptions,
    GoogleMapsMarker
} from 'ionic-native';
/*
 Generated class for the OrderTracking page.

 See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
 Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'page-order-tracking',
  templateUrl: 'order-tracking.html'
})
export class OrderTracking {

  map: GoogleMap;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.loadMap();
    });
  }

  loadMap(){

    let location = new GoogleMapsLatLng(-34.9290,138.6010);

    this.map = new GoogleMap('map', {
      'backgroundColor': 'white',
      'controls': {
        'compass': true,
        'myLocationButton': true,
        'indoorPicker': true,
        'zoom': true
      },
      'gestures': {
        'scroll': true,
        'tilt': true,
        'rotate': true,
        'zoom': true
      },
      'camera': {
        'latLng': location,
        'tilt': 30,
        'zoom': 15,
        'bearing': 50
      }
    });

    this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).subscribe(() => {
      console.log('Map is ready!');
    });

  }
}
```

**order-tracking.scss**

```
page-order-tracking {
  .scroll {
    height: 100%;
  }

  #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
  }


  ion-app._gmaps_cdv_ .nav-decor{
background-color: transparent !important;
 .tackdiv{
color:darkorange;
text-align: center;

  }
  .mytext{
margin-top: 10px;
color: lightgrey;
  }
  }
}
```

**order-tracking.html**

```
 <ion-content>
      <div id="map"></div>
<h1 class="tackdiv">Your order is dispatched </h1>
  <h4 class="mytext">Your order will be delivered in 32 mins</h4>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-avatar item-left>
      <img  src="assets/img/Umar.png">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h4>Umar </h4>
    <ion-icon name='call' item-right></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon name='mail' item-right></ion-icon>
  </ion-item>
    </ion-content>
```

Comment: Don't you have API key from Google in the code?

Comment: i have added API KEY while installing the cordova-plugin-googlemaps

Comment: in the plugin installation commond @Sela Yair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is a typical refresh problem.
Therefore, in **loadMap** function, please try appending the following line:

```
this.map.setCenter(location);
```

In addition, make sure that you have enabled the necessary Google APIs from [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/). Mine is as follows:

[image]

Comment: thanks for reply, i appended the above line but not working still showing blank area.

Comment: You might check your API configuration. Please see the changes that I made above.

Comment: Thanks! @Mete Cantimur after configuration it works!

Comment: Hi @MeteCantimur, I followed the same code and still I get a similar issue. When running on iOS simulator, the view becomes transparent with no map. BTW, I am trying to add a map on to an ionic-modal.

Comment: is there any solution to this ?